# The nonetype value comes from the django form

Tags: python, django, types

I am a beginner in Django. I have a form with a field "count_cont" .
And i want to get integer value from this field, but i have "nonetype".

```
count_cont = forms.IntegerField(max_value=5, min_value=1)
```

And i want to get integer value from this field, but i have "nonetype".

```
n=int(str(request.POST.get("count_cont")))
```

I try to convert it with int() and str() functions, but i get error

```
"invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'"
```

Comment: This is not a value problem.  The `count_cont` field was missing altogether from the submitted form data.

Comment: If you have a form, so why you are not using `int(form.cleaned_data.get('count_cont'))`